# client using coproc does not exit

Tags: bash, coproc

I have a filter like:

```
#!/bin/bash

while
read line
do
echo $line | tr "B" "b"
done
```

I have a client that use that filter using coproc like:

```
#!/bin/bash

coproc ./filter
echo Bogus >&"${COPROC[1]}"
cat <&"${COPROC[0]}"
```

Now the client does not exit. I have to use <kbd>Ctrl + C</kbd> to exit.

I want the client to exit when it reach the last line.

How to achieve that?

Comment: This bash code will alter whitespace too, among other possible transformations (try sending the string `"*"` to the filter). use `IFS= read -r line` and `printf '%s\n' "$line" | tr 'B' 'b'` or `tr 'B' 'b' <<< "$line"` (or don't use tr: `printf '%s\n' "${line//B/b}"`)

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you used a coproc? Looks like a simple pipe could be easier. If you want to pipe the output of many commands you can group them with `{ echo a; echo b; echo c; } | filter` (the commands do not need to be on one line)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you do not want to send anything more *inform* the other side about it by closing the file descriptor.

```
coproc ./filter
echo Bogus >&"${COPROC[1]}"
exec {COPROC[1]}>&-
cat <&"${COPROC[0]}"
```

That way, `read line` will exit with failure, so `while` will break and filter script will exit.